# set alias in bash got "syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Tags: r, bash, shell, shiny

I want to run a shiny app in command line and it did well:

```
R -e "shiny::runApp('~/User/Appname',launch.browser=TRUE)"
```

But got error: syntax error near unexpected token `(' once I set an alias in .profile:

```
alias report="R -e "shiny::runApp('~/User/Appname',launch.browser=TRUE)""
```

Need your help here, I guess something wrong in the quotes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using double quotes inside double quotes you need to escape the inner ones like this:

```
alias report="R -e \"shiny::runApp('~/User/Appname',launch.browser=TRUE)\""
```

However cleaner approach is to have a shell function instead and avoid all the escaping:

```
report() {
   R -e "shiny::runApp('~/User/Appname',launch.browser=TRUE)"
}
```

Comment: Oh, Thanks Anubhava!